# numpy reverse multidimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

What is the simplest way in numpy to reverse the most inner values of an array like this:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 4]],

   [[1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 4]]])
```

so that I get the following result:

```
array([[[2, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 2, 2, 2],
    [4, 3, 3, 3]],

   [[2, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 2, 2, 2],
    [4, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[10, 1, 1, 2],
               [2, 2, 2, 3],
               [3, 3, 3, 4]],
              [[1, 1, 1, 2],
               [2, 2, 2, 3],
               [3, 3, 3, 4]]])
```

and the reverse along the last dimension is:

```
b = a[:,:,::-1]
```

or

```
b = a[...,::-1]
```

although I like the later less since the first two dimensions are implicit and it is more difficult to see what is going on.

Comment: a[..., 3::-1] is still OK, but now a surprise: a[..., 3:-1:-1] results in: array([], shape=(2, 3, 0), dtype=int64). It is numpy 1.7.1. Unpleasant, right?

Answer (score 1):

For each of the inner array you can use [fliplr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html).
It flips the entries in each row in the left/right direction. Columns are preserved, but appear in a different order than before.

Sample usage:

```
import numpy as np
initial_array = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
                          [2, 2, 2, 3],
                          [3, 3, 3, 4]],
                         [[1, 1, 1, 2],
                          [2, 2, 2, 3],
                          [3, 3, 3, 4]]])
index=0
initial_shape = initial_array.shape
reversed=np.empty(shape=initial_shape)
for inner_array in initial_array:
    reversed[index] = np.fliplr(inner_array)
    index += 1
```

printing reversed

Output:

```
array([[[2, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 3, 3, 3]],
       [[2, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

Make sure your input array for fliplr function must be at least 2-D.

Moreover if you want to flip array in the up/down direction. You can also use [flipud](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `numpy.flip()`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
               [2, 2, 2, 3],
               [3, 3, 3, 4]],
              [[1, 1, 1, 2],
               [2, 2, 2, 3],
               [3, 3, 3, 4]]])
print(np.flip(a, axis=2))
```

Which gives:

```
array([[[2, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 3, 3, 3]],
       [[2, 1, 1, 1],
        [3, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

as required. The input array is three dimensional due to the extra square brackets. So, flipping along `axis=2`, means flipping the 3rd axis (since the count starts at 0).

Note that this returns a view, not a copy (see [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)).