# multidimensional numpy array -- reverse along a given axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a multidimensional array with a shape that I don't know until runtime.

How can I reverse it along a given axis k, also not known until runtime?

The notation `somearray[:,:,::-1,:,:]` relies on static dimension references, [as in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416170/numpy-reverse-multidimensional-array), so I can't use it here.

Answer (score 9):

You can either construct a tuple of `slice` objects such as @ali_m suggests, or do something like this:

```
reversed_arr = np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(arr, 0, k)[::-1], 0, k)
```

This places the desired axis at the front of the shape tuple, then reverses that first axis, and then returns it to its original position.

Some people think this approach lacks readability, but I disagree.

Comment: Since it returns a view, array is not copied, nice approach. Also, I found this approach the most elegant when array on LHS needs to be changed in given `axis`.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a tuple of `slice` objects for this:

```
def reversedim(M,k=0):
    idx = tuple((slice(None,None,-1) if ii == k else slice(None) 
            for ii in xrange(M.ndim)))
    return M[idx]
```

Comment: @NilsWerner I don't think so. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) - "Note that slices of arrays do not copy the internal array data but also produce new views of the original data."