# How do I reverse the first four elements of the 1st axis and reversing the 2nd axis of a numpy array in a single operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `M` of shape `(n, 1000, 6)`. This can be thought of as n matrices with 1000 rows and 6 columns. For each matrix I would like to reverse the order of the rows (i.e. the top row is now at the bottom and vice versa) and then reverse the order of just the first 4 columns (so column 0 is now column 3, column 1 is column 2, column 2 is column 1 and column 3 is column 0 but column 4 is still column 4 and column 5 is still column 5). I would like to do this in a single operation, without doing indexing on the left side of the expression, so this would not be acceptable:

`M[:,0:4,:] = M[:,0:4,:][:,::-1,:]
M[:,:,:] = M[:,:,::-1]`

The operation needs to be achieveable using Keras backend which disallowes this. It must be of the form

`M = M[indexing here that solves the task]`

If I wanted to reverse the order of all the columns instead of just the first 4 this could easily be achieved with `M = M[:,::-1,::-1]` so I've being trying to modify this to achieve my goal but unfortunately can't work out how. Is this even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416170/numpy-reverse-multidimensional-array

Comment: @Dadep that question is for reversing a single axis, this isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M[:, ::-1, [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5]]`