# How to sort python csr_matix by data

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I want to get keywords of a text by tfidf method with sklenrn

I have got tfidf module, see code below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
tfidf_vect = text.TfidfVectorizer()
texts = get_text_list()
tfidf = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(texts)
```

now , inputting a new documents as text

```
res = tfidf_vect.transform(text)
```

The res is a csr_matrix. The res.indices is positions of words and res.data is tfidf value.

**How to sort this res by res.data**

reference:http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html

Comment: Is the goal to sort it by descending order of TF-IDF scores?  `tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()` will give you the word for each position in the TF-IDF vectors.

Comment: @confuser, Thanks. Yes, I want to sort it by descending order of TF-IDF scores. Do you know the method?

Comment: `res.toarray().argsort()` will return the indices in **ascending** order of TF-IDF score, and you can use those indices to look up the word list you get from `tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()`.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @confuser, Thank you so much! It helps me a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order, refer it get descending order:)