# TensorFlow cookbook skip-gram model with negative similarity

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am currently going through Google's [TensorFlow cookbook](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/07_Natural_Language_Processing/04_Working_With_Skip_Gram_Embeddings/04_working_with_skipgram.ipynb):

This is a TensorFlow implementation of the skip-gram model.

On line 272, the author decides to negatively multiply the similarity matrix `(-sim[j, :])`. I am a little bit confused why do we need to negatively multiply the similarity matrix in a skip-gram model. Any ideas?

```
for j in range(len(valid_words)):
        valid_word = word_dictionary_rev[valid_examples[j]]
        top_k = 5 # number of nearest neighbors
        **nearest = (-sim[j, :]).argsort()[1:top_k+1]**
        log_str = "Nearest to {}:".format(valid_word)
        for k in range(top_k):
            close_word = word_dictionary_rev[nearest[k]]
            score = sim[j,nearest[k]]
            log_str = "%s %s," % (log_str, close_word)
        print(log_str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through this example step by step:

- First, there's a `similarity` tensor. It is defined as a matrix of pairwise cosine similarities between embedding vectors:

  ```py
  # Cosine similarity between words
  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normalized_embeddings,valid_dataset)
  similarity= tf.matmul(valid_embeddings,normalized_embeddings,transpose_b=True)
  ```

  The matrix is computed for all validations words and all dictionary words, and contains numbers between `[-1,1]`. In this example, the vocab size is 10000 and the validation set consists of 5 words, so the shape of the `similarity` matrix is `(5, 10000)`.
- This matrix is evaluated to a numpy array `sim`:

  ```py
  sim = sess.run(similarity, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  ```

  Consequently, `sim.shape = (5, 10000)` as well.
- Next, this line:

  ```py
  nearest = (-sim[j, :]).argsort()[1:top_k+1]
  ```

  ... computes the `top_k` *nearest* word indices to the current word `j`. Take a look at [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) method. The negation is just a numpy way of sorting [in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16486252/712995). If there were no minus, the result would be the `top_k` *furthest* words from the dictionary, which won't indicate word2vec has learned anything.

  Also note that the range is `[1:top_k+1]`, not `[:top_k]`, because the 0-th word is the current validation word itself. There's no point in printing that the closest word to "love" is... "love".

  The result of this line would be an array like `[  73 1684  850 1912  326]`, which corresponds to words `sex, fine, youd, trying, execution`.