# Sort date in string format in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this, how to sort this.

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['Oct20','Nov19','Jan19','Sep20','Dec20']})


        Date
    0   Oct20
    1   Nov19
    2   Jan19
    3   Sep20
    4   Dec20
```

I familiar in sorting list of dates(string)

```
 a.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y"))
```

Any thoughts? Should i split it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes and get positions of sorted values by [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) what is used for change ordering with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b%y').argsort()]
print (df)
    Date
2  Jan19
1  Nov19
3  Sep20
0  Oct20
4  Dec20
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b%y'))
0   2020-10-01
1   2019-11-01
2   2019-01-01
3   2020-09-01
4   2020-12-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do argsort() in descending order.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum - Yop [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order).

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum - `df = df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b%y').argsort()[::-1]]`