# Pandas groupby, select 3 elements with largest values, and take the mean of each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange'], 'columnB': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, -0.55, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70, 0.90]})

    columnA columnB
0   apple   0.10
1   apple   -0.15
2   apple   0.25
3   apple   -0.55
4   orange  0.50
5   orange  -0.51
6   orange  0.70
7   orange  0.90
```

I want to group the data by `columnA` and take the mean of the 3 rows with the largest values (in terms of absolute value) in `columnB`.

The first thing I tried was:

```
df.reindex(df['columnB'].abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index).groupby('columnA').head(3).groupby('columnA')[['columnB']].mean().reset_index()


columnA columnB
0   apple   -0.150000
1   orange  0.363333
```

This looks correct, but I wanted to try and simplify with this:

```
df.iloc[df['columnB'].abs().argsort()].groupby('columnA').head(3).groupby('columnA')[['columnB']].mean().reset_index()

    columnA columnB
0   apple   0.066667
1   orange  0.230000
```

This is not correct. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert values to negative or change order of positions, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16486252):

```
df1 = (df.iloc[(-df['columnB'].abs()).argsort()]
          .groupby('columnA')['columnB'].apply(lambda x: x.head(3).mean())
          .reset_index())
print (df1)
  columnA   columnB
0   apple -0.150000
1  orange  0.363333
```

---

```
df1 = (df.iloc[df['columnB'].abs().argsort()[::-1]]
          .groupby('columnA')['columnB'].apply(lambda x: x.head(3).mean())
          .reset_index())
print (df1)
  columnA   columnB
0   apple -0.150000
1  orange  0.363333
```

Comment: So all I need to do is reverse the order of argsort?

Comment: Any reason to use one approach over the other? Do you have a preference?

Comment: @BuffaloCollector - hmmm, I think argsort solution should be faster, I prefer convert values to negative.