# Applying calculations to filtered values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas.

Consider this my DataFrame:

**df**

```
Search              Impressions     Clicks      Transactions    ContainsBest       ContainsFree         Country
Best phone          10              5           1               True               False                UK
Best free phone     15              4           2               True               True                 UK
free phone          20              3           4               False              True                 UK
good phone          13              1           5               False              False                US
just a free phone   12              3           4               False              True                 US
```

I have columns `ContainsBest` and `ContainsFree`. I want to sum all `Impressions`, `Clicks` and `Transactions` where `ContainsBest` is `True`, then I want to sum `Impressions`, `Clicks` and `Transactions` where `ContainsFree` is True and do the same per unique value in column `Country`. So the new DataFrame would look like this:

**output_df**

```
Country             Impressions     Clicks      Transactions
UK                  45              12          7
ContainsBest        25              9           3
ContainsFree        35              7           6

US                  25              4           9
ContainsBest        0               0           0
ContainsFree        12              3           4
```

For this I would understand I would need to use something like the following:

```
uk_toal_impressions = df['Impressions'].sum().where(df['Country']=='UK')

uk_best_impressions = df['Impressions'].sum().where(df['Country']=='UK' & df['ContainsBest'])

uk_free_impressions = df['Impressions'].sum().where(df['Country']=='UK' & df['ContainsFree'])
```

Then I would apply the same logic for `Clicks` and `Transactions` and redo the same code for `Country` `US`.

The second thing I am trying to achieve is to add column `TopCategories` per `Country` and `Impressions`, `Clicks` and `Transactions`, so that my `final_output_df` would look like this:

**final_output_df**

```
Country             Impressions     Clicks      Transactions        TopCategoriesForImpressions     TopCategoriesForClicks          TopCategoriesForTransactions     
UK                  45              12          7                   ContainsFree                    ContainsBest                    ContainsFree
ContainsBest        25              9           3                   ContainsBest                    ContainsFree                    ContainsBest
ContainsFree        35              7           6

US                  25              4           9                   ContainsFree                    ContainsFree                    ContainsFree
ContainsBest        0               0           0
ContainsFree        12              3           4
```

The column `TopCategoriesForxx` logic is a simple sort of `ContainsBest` and `ContainsFree` rows under `Country` column. So that the `TopCategoriesForImpressions` for `UK` country is

1. ContainsFree
2. ContainsBest

While the `TopCategoriesForClicks` for `UK` country is:

1. ContainsBest
2. ContainsFree

I understand I would need to use something like this:

```
TopCategoriesForImpressions = output_df['Impressions'].sort_values(by='Impressions', ascending=False).where(output_df['Country']=='UK')
```

I just find difficult to put everything to look as in my last `final_output_df`. Also, I would assume I do not need `output_df` to be created, just wanted to add it for better understanding of what my steps are to achieve the `final_output_df`.

**So my questions are:**

1. How to apply calculations based on one and multiple conditions? See row `ContainsBest` and `ContainsFree`
2. How can I sort column values based on a condition? See column `TopCategoriesForImpressions`
3. In reality, I have 70 countries and 20 columns `Containsxxx`, is there a way to achieve this without adding conditions for 70 countries and 20 `Containsxxx` columns?

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of solution should be:

```
#removed unnecessary column Search and added ContainAll column filled Trues
df1 = df.drop('Search', 1).assign(ContainAll = True)

#columns for tests
cols1 = ['Impressions','Clicks','Transactions']
cols2 = ['ContainsBest','ContainsFree','ContainAll']

print (df1[cols2].dtypes)
ContainsBest    bool
ContainsFree    bool
ContainAll      bool
dtype: object

print (df1[cols1].dtypes)
Impressions     int64
Clicks          int64
Transactions    int64
dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df1.melt(['Country'] + cols1, var_name='Type', value_name='mask'))
   Country  Impressions  Clicks  Transactions          Type   mask
0       UK           10       5             1  ContainsBest   True
1       UK           15       4             2  ContainsBest   True
2       UK           20       3             4  ContainsBest  False
3       US           13       1             5  ContainsBest  False
4       US           12       3             4  ContainsBest  False
5       UK           10       5             1  ContainsFree  False
6       UK           15       4             2  ContainsFree   True
7       UK           20       3             4  ContainsFree   True
8       US           13       1             5  ContainsFree  False
9       US           12       3             4  ContainsFree   True
10      UK           10       5             1    ContainAll   True
11      UK           15       4             2    ContainAll   True
12      UK           20       3             4    ContainAll   True
13      US           13       1             5    ContainAll   True
14      US           12       3             4    ContainAll   True

print (df1.melt(['Country'] + cols1, var_name='Type', value_name='mask').query('mask'))
   Country  Impressions  Clicks  Transactions          Type  mask
0       UK           10       5             1  ContainsBest  True
1       UK           15       4             2  ContainsBest  True
6       UK           15       4             2  ContainsFree  True
7       UK           20       3             4  ContainsFree  True
9       US           12       3             4  ContainsFree  True
10      UK           10       5             1    ContainAll  True
11      UK           15       4             2    ContainAll  True
12      UK           20       3             4    ContainAll  True
13      US           13       1             5    ContainAll  True
14      US           12       3             4    ContainAll  True
```

---

```
#all possible combinations of Country and boolean columns
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Country'].unique(), cols2], 
                                  names=['Country','Type'])

#reshape by melt for all boolean column to one mask column
#filter Trues by loc and aggregate sum
#add 0 rows by reindex
df1 = (df1.melt(['Country'] + cols1, var_name='Type', value_name='mask')
          .query('mask')
          .drop('mask', axis=1)
          .groupby(['Country','Type'])
          .sum()
          .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
          .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Country          Type  Impressions  Clicks  Transactions
0      UK  ContainsBest           25       9             3
1      UK  ContainsFree           35       7             6
2      UK    ContainAll           45      12             7
3      US  ContainsBest            0       0             0
4      US  ContainsFree           12       3             4
5      US    ContainAll           25       4             9
```

For second is possible filter rows for check sortings with `numpy.argsort` with [descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486305/2901002) per groups:

```
def f(x):
    i = x.index.to_numpy()
    a = i[(-x.to_numpy()).argsort(axis=0)]
    return pd.DataFrame(a, columns=x.columns)


df2 = (df1[df1['Type'].isin(['ContainsBest','ContainsFree']) &
          ~df1[cols1].eq(0).all(1)]
           .set_index('Type')
           .groupby('Country')[cols1]
           .apply(f)
           .add_prefix('TopCategoriesFor')
           .rename_axis(['Country','Type'])
           .rename({0:'ContainsBest', 1:'ContainsFree'})
)
print (df2)
                     TopCategoriesForImpressions TopCategoriesForClicks  \
Country Type                                                              
UK      ContainsBest                ContainsFree           ContainsBest   
        ContainsFree                ContainsBest           ContainsFree   
US      ContainsBest                ContainsFree           ContainsFree   

                     TopCategoriesForTransactions  
Country Type                                       
UK      ContainsBest                 ContainsFree  
        ContainsFree                 ContainsBest  
US      ContainsBest                 ContainsFree
```

---

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=['Country','Type'])
print (df3)
  Country          Type  Impressions  Clicks  Transactions  \
0      UK  ContainsBest           25       9             3   
1      UK  ContainsFree           35       7             6   
2      UK    ContainAll           45      12             7   
3      US  ContainsBest            0       0             0   
4      US  ContainsFree           12       3             4   
5      US    ContainAll           25       4             9   

  TopCategoriesForImpressions TopCategoriesForClicks  \
0                ContainsFree           ContainsBest   
1                ContainsBest           ContainsFree   
2                         NaN                    NaN   
3                ContainsFree           ContainsFree   
4                         NaN                    NaN   
5                         NaN                    NaN   

  TopCategoriesForTransactions  
0                 ContainsFree  
1                 ContainsBest  
2                          NaN  
3                 ContainsFree  
4                          NaN  
5                          NaN
```

Comment: for some reason I do get the same structure as you have but all of my values are `0`. Any idea why would that be the case? I am writing the `df` to a csv before using the code you have added, maybe `to_csv` makes the `df` empty?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - hmmm, are data numeric?

Comment: checking that right now. I also do get a warning `FutureWarning:
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.` Not sure if that can affect the script.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - One idea what is `print (df1.melt(['Country'] + cols1, var_name='Type', value_name='mask').dtypes)` ?

Comment: yes, `Impressions`, `Transactions` and `Clicks` are type `int64` while `Country` is an `object`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - is column `mask` boolean?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I can add some `print`s for check where is problem, give me some time.

Comment: answer to your question - the type is `Country       object
Impressions     float64
Clicks          float64
Transactions    float64
Type             object
mask             object
dtype: object`, I know checked and there are one value in `Impressions` of `8` and 3 values of `1` in `Clicks` column.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - there is problem, there should be boolean in mask column

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - If check `print (df1[cols2].dtype)` after first row of code `df1 = df.drop('Search', 1).assign(ContainAll = True)` return all `boolean` ?

Comment: yes, all return `bool`, `ContainsBest    bool
ContainsFree    bool
ContainAll      bool`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Added some prints to answer for check it.

Comment: looks like it works, previously I have added more `Containsxxx` columns, not sure why it broke the code. In reality, I have like 15 `Containsxxx` fields which I add to your defined `cols2` list. Will try adding one by one to check where it breaks. Or does there other changes that need to be made in order to include more items, not only in `col2`?

Comment: managed to put everything in place with my 15 `contains` columns and sort them. Thank you very much for your help, just one thing I cant quite understand, how does the sorting work for each of 3 `contains` columns. I see you have a defined function but do not invoke it anywhere. Thats some high level code, thank you so much sir!