# What is the sorting direction (ascending or descending) of numpy.argsort?

Tags: python, numpy

The function `numpy.argsort` seems to return sorted 1D-array in increasing order. For example,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 1, 2])
ind = np.argsort(x)
x[ind]
```

returns `array([1, 2, 3])`. However, I've read through its [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) but could not find this information.

Could you please explain how to get it?

Comment: Python's native sorts always sorts ascending by default, that's probably why this is not mentioned in the docs. But you even tried it and it's ascending; how many answers could there be to this question?

Comment: see also https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/14989 to include a `reverse` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So most sorting algorithms sort in ascending order if nothing else is specified. You can always just reverse the output yourself to get the sorting in descending order

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 1, 2])
ascending = np.argsort(x)
descending = ascending[::-1]
```

For more information on sorting direction of `np.argsort`, you can have a look at this post [Is it possible to use argsort in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order/16486305)

EDIT: I found a reference to the sort order of numpy here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort where it is mentioned that sorting is done in lexicographic order by default

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @RandomGuy I explain the algorithm is sorting in ascending order, and how to reverse it in case you want - that seems to me to answer the question. What do you miss in an answer?

Comment: He asked for where to find this information in the documentation, not how to reverse the `ind` array (which is quite trivial)

Comment: @RandomGuy sure, but that information is not part of numpys documentation - likely because sorting algorithms default to using ascending order

Comment: @RandomGuy nevermind, actually found a reference to using lexicographic order in the `numpy.sort` documentation - thanks for being persistant haha