# Get the index of the largest two values per row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

For each row, I would like to get the index of the largest two values.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[7, 5, 6],
              [4, 9, 3],
              [1, 6, 7]])
```

Here's the result I would like to obtain:

```
[0, 2]
[1, 0]
[2, 1]
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Are the sublists always of length 3? If so, get the index of the minimum and use that to eliminate the index that isn't wanted.

Comment: Additionally, does the order of the resulting indices matter? Your desired output seems to prioritise the largest value of the array first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use argsort in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order)

Comment: They are not of length 3, it's a minimal example. And yes, the order of the resulting indices matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.argsort` along the second axis and take last two values reversed.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[7, 5, 6],
              [4, 9, 3],
              [1, 6, 7]])

ind = x.argsort(axis=1)[:,-1:-3:-1]
print(ind)
[[0 2]
 [1 0]
 [2 1]]
```

Comment: Some variable to select the top-k would be appreciated