# Using np.argsort()[::-1] to sort in descending order with same values

Tags: python, numpy, np.argsort

For example,
I have a numpy array like: a = np.array([0.5, 0.1, 0.5)].

When I use np.argsort(a)[::-1] to sort my array in descending order, it returns:

> 2, 0, 1

Which is technically correct, as np.argsort(a) would return:

> 1, 0, 2

and I am just reversing the order.

However, I want the sort to be in the order as the original array, so I would like the return to be:

> 0, 2, 1

How do I do that? Is there a better function than np.argsort()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use argsort in descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 2):

I would try like this

```
np.argsort(-1 * a)
```

Comment: There're two slightly more efficient solutions in [this duplicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486305/15032126) (see the comments also)