# Numpy.cumsum in reverse

Tags: python, numpy

Here is cumsum in the forward direction:

```
> import numpy as np
> np.arange(10)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
> np.cumsum(np.arange(10))
array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45])
```

I would like to perform cumsum in the reverse direction, which would give me

```
array([45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17, 9])
```

What is the simplest and most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest I can think of and that produces your result is

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
```

which gives

```
array([45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9])
```

**EDIT**: As *dg99* pointed out, there's also [a post about the efficiency of reversing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771428/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-numpy-array). Accordingly, `[::-1]` seems to be the best you can get. Thus, `x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]` also seems to be the most efficient way to do your reverse cumsum.

**2nd EDIT**:
For completeness, if you have a multi-dimensional array, you can get the reverse cumsum along the innermost dimension via:

```
x[...,::-1].cumsum(axis=-1)[...,::-1]
```

For instance,

```
x = np.array(((range(10), range(10)), (range(10), range(10))))
print(x)
```

prints

```
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],

   [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]])
```

and

```
 x[...,::-1].cumsum(axis=-1)[...,::-1]
```

returns

```
array([[[45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9],
    [45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9]],

   [[45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9],
    [45, 45, 44, 42, 39, 35, 30, 24, 17,  9]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
np.cumsum(np.arange(10)[::-1])
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6771428/731240) which discusses reversing numpy arrays.