# Ordering the elements in a matrix with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning Python and I have the following doubt about the `NumPy` library:

I have the following 2x2 matrix:

```
a = np.array([[2,4],[5,1]])
```

This matrix gives the following output:

```
[[2 4]  [5 1]]
```

Nevertheless, I would like to reorder the elements to obtain:

```
[[5 1]  [2 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean reverse the order, just use `a[::-1]`.

If you mean swapping: `a[1], a[0] = a[0], a[1].copy()`. Here you need the `.copy()` since slicing a Numpy array only creates a view, not copying the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use np.flipud(a)! Your question is kind of a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771428/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-numpy-array). Your question is also easily answered if you just search documentation for basic numpy functions ([see documentation for numpy.flipud](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html)). I realize you may be a beginner ( keep learning :) ), but stack overflow isn't really intended for such simple questions, it's for questions that are not answered in any documentation. So next time you're not sure I suggest searching through python documentation or just look at previously answered stack overflow questions.