# Numpy array neither C or F contiguous implications

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, python-internals

## TL;DR Question

Regarding numpy arrays that are neighter C or F contiguous (array's c_contiguous and f_contiguous flags are False):

1. Can an array really be neither C or F contiguous? Or falsy flags just mean numpy can't figure out the correct contigious type?
2. What are the performance implications on such arrays? Are there any optimizations we miss when staying in this state?

An array for example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 1000, 3), dtype='uint8')
arr = arr[:, :, ::-1]
assert arr.flags.c_contiguous is False
assert arr.flags.f_contiguous is False
```

## Background

I am trying to optimize a simple code block which is called many times during a program.
This code block is responsible to load PIL Image, convert it to a numpy array, inverse it's channels and return it.
Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_image(path):
    arr = np.asarray(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
    return arr[:, :, ::-1].copy()
```

The original `copy()` call was there in order to enforce the return value to be C-order array, however, I was wondering if there's a way to achieve the same effect without copying the array every time, as it sounds very expensive.
I tried replacing the `copy()` call with `np.ascontiguousarray()`, but benchmarks showed they're the same, thus I guess it also performs copying behind the scenes.

I decided to apply this solution in the end:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_image(path):
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
    return arr[:, :, ::-1]
```

Here, I convert the image to a C-ordered array, which could incur a copy behind the scenes, but in fact it doesn't, because in the benchmarks this function is X3-X4 faster than the previous one.
However I want to be sure I do not cancel any future optimizations by returning an array which is neither C or F ordered.

Comment: If you're only doing a single operation, like inverting the channels, and also you have to slice the data, then I would guess that any effort to get contiguous data is useless - there's no way to avoid copying all the data, which is going to involve all of the same cache misses as it would take just processing the data as is.

Comment: Why don't you try `OpenCV`? it reads images faster than `PIL` and gives you BGR images as numpy arrays.

Comment: In the codebase I work on, the call was switched from OpenCV to PIL since it gives no feedback on errors while reading the image. There's an explicit comment on that.

Comment: Though that's a good direction, I'll try to figure out what errors were missing and see if I can re-use OpenCV again. But it was switched months ago.

Comment: The distinction between a `view` and a `copy` is important, but whether something is F,C or neither contiguous is usually not - unless some downstream operation objects.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't quite understand your comment, meant to say not important?
and of course many downstream operations are to be expected, it's images in a batch. they're going to have some scaling and normalization operations

Comment: part of this happens because the reversed array is a _view_ (`np.flip(arr, -1)` will also do this) see [Most efficient way to reverse a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771428/) you can check for a copy with [`arr2.base`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524664/)