# reverse order within sublist in numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, reverse, sublist

I have two numpy arrays:

```
Values = numpy.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16])
Lengths = numpy.array([4, 3, 3])
```

What would be an efficient way to in numpy to reverse the order within the sublist to get this?

```
[8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 16, 15, 14]
```

I have tried `for` loop, but I believe there should be a more efficient way to do it using numpy functions.

Comment: For lists and arrays, indexing with `::-1` reverses

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by splitting the array (using [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)) at the desired indices, given by `np.cumsum(Lengths)`, and then concatenating (using [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)) them after each is reversed.

```py
import numpy as np

Values = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16])
Lengths = np.array([4, 3, 3])

res = np.concatenate([split[::-1] for split in np.split(Values, np.cumsum(Lengths))])
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[ 8  7  6  5  3  2  1 16 15 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

For a vectorial solution, you can craft a sorter array with [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), then use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to reorder your array

```
a = np.repeat(np.arange(len(Lengths)), Lengths)[::-1]
# array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

out = Values[len(Values)-1-np.argsort(a)]
```

Output:

```
array([ 8,  7,  6,  5,  3,  2,  1, 16, 15, 14])
```

Intermediate:

```
len(Values)-1-np.argsort(a)
# array([3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

Values = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16])
Lengths = np.array([4, 3, 3])

splits = np.split(Values, np.cumsum(Lengths)[:-1]) #splits into 3 parts
reversed_list = [np.flip(split) for split in splits] #flip/reverse all the 3 parts

result = np.concatenate(reversed_list) # join all 3 parts
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771428/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-numpy-array) discussion, slicing is the among the fastest techniques, you can use for splitting. The following code uses only slicing and hence doesn't use any additional space or copying.

```
import numpy
Values = numpy.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16])
Lengths = numpy.array([4, 3, 3])  
start = 0
end = 0
for i in range(len(Lengths)):
  end = end + Lengths[i]
  if i == 0:  ## Isolate the first scenario as splitting doesn't accept -1 as second argument. [end:-1:step] is not valid
    Values[0:end] = Values[end-1::-1]
  else:
    Values[start:end] = Values[end-1:start-1:-1]
  start = end
  print(Values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of indexes that reverse the positions relatively to each chunk's last index.  Then use that as an indirection on the values array.

```
import numpy as np

values  = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16])
lengths = np.array([4, 3, 3])

s      = np.cumsum(lengths) - 1
s[1:] += s[:-1] + 1
i      = np.repeat(s, lengths) - np.arange(values.size)


print(values[i])    
# [ 8  7  6  5  3  2  1 16 15 14]
```