# Reversed array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[Numpy tentative tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) suggests that `a[ : :-1]` is a reversed `a`. Can someone explain me how we got there?

I understand that `a[:]` means for each element of `a` (with axis=0). Next `:` should denote the number of elements to skip (or period) from my understanding.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation -- This is for python proper, but numpy obeys all of the conventions like a good 3rd party package.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371049/875127 for a good explanation of how basic slicing in numpy returns a view and not a copy of the original array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have noted, this is a python slicing technique, and numpy just follows suit.  Hopefully this helps explain how it works:

The last bit is the stepsize.  The `1` indicates to step by one element at a time, the `-` does that in reverse.

Blanks indicate the first and last, unless you have a negative stepsize, in which case they indicate last and first:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(5)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: a[0:5:1]
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [5]: a[0:5:-1]
Out[5]: array([], dtype=int64)

In [6]: a[5:0:-1]
Out[6]: array([4, 3, 2, 1])

In [7]: a[::-2]
Out[7]: array([4, 2, 0])
```

Line 5 gives an empty array since it tries to step backwards from the `0`th element to the `5`th.
The slice doesn't include the 'endpoint' (named last element) so line 6 misses `0` when going backwards.

Comment: Why does `a[5:-1:-1]` return `array([], dtype=int64)` and not the right answer `array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])`?

Comment: @AbhishekNaik In python indexing, [negative numbers count from the end toward](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) the beginning, so `a[-1]` is the last element.  Thus, `a[5:-1:-1]` is equivalent to `a[5:4:-1]`, so the empty array *is* the right answer.  To get to the end (in either direction) use `None` or leave it blank: `a[5:None:-1]` or `a[5::-1]`.

Answer (score 21):

It isn't numpy, it's Python.

In Python, there are slices for sequence/iterable, which come in the following syntax

```
seq[start:stop:step] => a slice from start to stop, stepping step each time.
```

All the arguments are optional, but a `:` has to be there for Python to recognize this as a slice.

Negative values, for step, also work to make a copy of the same sequence/iterable in reverse order:

```
>>> L = range(10)
>>> L[::-1] 
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

And numpy follows that "rule" like any good 3rd party library..

```
>>> a = numpy.array(range(10))
>>> a[::-1]
array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

See [this link](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't specific to numpy, the slice `a[::-1]` is equivalent to [`slice(None, None, -1)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice), where the first argument is the start index, the second argument is the end index, and the third argument is the step.  `None` for start or stop will have the same behavior as using the beginning or end of the sequence, and `-1` for step will iterate over the sequence in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#reversed) Python built-in:

```
import numpy as np

bins = np.arange(0.0, 1.1, .1)
for i in reversed(bins):
    print(i)
```

Comment: how to reversed enumerate numpy with index  9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0?