# Calculate average of every x rows in a table and create new table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a long table of data (~200 rows by 50 columns) and I need to create a code that can calculate the mean values of every two rows and for each column in the table with the final output being a new table of the mean values. This is obviously crazy to do in Excel! I use python3 and I am aware of some similar questions:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379311/fast-way-to-take-average-of-every-n-rows-in-a-npy-array), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463609/calculating-an-average-for-every-x-number-of-lines) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956309/averaging-over-every-n-elements-of-a-numpy-array). But none of these helps as I need some elegant code to work with multiple columns and produces an organised data table. By the way my original datatable has been imported using pandas and is defined as a dataframe but could not find an easy way to do this in pandas. Help is much appreciated.

An example of the table (short version) is:

```
a   b   c   d
2   50  25  26
4   11  38  44
6   33  16  25
8   37  27  25
10  28  48  32
12  47  35  45
14  8   16  7
16  12  16  30
18  22  39  29
20  9   15  47
```

Expected mean table:

```
a    b     c     d
3   30.5  31.5  35
7   35    21.5  25
11  37.5  41.5  38.5
15  10    16    18.5
19  15.5  27    38
```

Answer (score 63):

You can create an artificial group using `df.index//2` (or as @DSM pointed out, using `np.arange(len(df))//2` - so that it works for all indices) and then use groupby:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).mean()
Out[13]: 
      a     b     c     d
0   3.0  30.5  31.5  35.0
1   7.0  35.0  21.5  25.0
2  11.0  37.5  41.5  38.5
3  15.0  10.0  16.0  18.5
4  19.0  15.5  27.0  38.0
```

Comment: I found something close [here](stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table) BUT your answer if very elegant and compact. Thank you so much! Just out of interest what does the first forward slash means in df.index//2?

Comment: You are welcome. That is for integer division so that both 2//2 and 3//2 yield 1, 4//2 and 5//2 yield 2... (and put into the same group).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It might be better to group on `np.arange(len(df))//2` instead, in case the index isn't simply 0,1,2.. etc.

Comment: And a bit faster is `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//2).mean()` ;)

Answer (score 33):

You can approach this problem using `pd.rolling()` to create a rolling average  and then just grab every second element using `iloc`

```
df = df.rolling(2).mean() 
df = df.iloc[::2, :]
```

Note that the first observation will be missing (i.e. the rolling starts at the top) so make sure to check that your data is sorted how you need it.

Comment: This is so much more elegant than the previous answers.

Answer (score 9):

NumPythonic way would be to extract the elements as a NumPy array with `df.values`, then reshape to a `3D` array with `2` elements along `axis=1` and `4` along `axis=2` and perform the average reduction along `axis=1` and finally convert back to a dataframe, like so -

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]).mean(1))
```

As it turns out, you can introduce NumPy's very efficient tool : [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to do this `average-reduction` as a combination of `sum-reduction` and `scaling-down`, like so -

```
pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ijk->ik',df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]))/2.0)
```

Please note that the proposed approaches assume that the number of rows is divisible by `2`.

Also as [`noted by @DSM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table#comment61195916_36810721), to preserve the column names, you need to add `columns=df.columns` when converting back to Dataframe, i.e. -

```
pd.DataFrame(...,columns=df.columns)
```

Sample run -

```
>>> df
    0   1   2   3
0   2  50  25  26
1   4  11  38  44
2   6  33  16  25
3   8  37  27  25
4  10  28  48  32
5  12  47  35  45
6  14   8  16   7
7  16  12  16  30
8  18  22  39  29
9  20   9  15  47
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]).mean(1))
    0     1     2     3
0   3  30.5  31.5  35.0
1   7  35.0  21.5  25.0
2  11  37.5  41.5  38.5
3  15  10.0  16.0  18.5
4  19  15.5  27.0  38.0
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ijk->ik',df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]))/2.0)
    0     1     2     3
0   3  30.5  31.5  35.0
1   7  35.0  21.5  25.0
2  11  37.5  41.5  38.5
3  15  10.0  16.0  18.5
4  19  15.5  27.0  38.0
```

Runtime tests -

In this section, let's test out all the three approaches listed thus far to solve the problem for performance, including [`@ayhan's solution with groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36810658/3293881).

```
In [24]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(200,50))

In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(A)

In [26]: %timeit df.groupby(df.index//2).mean() # @ayhan's solution
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]).mean(1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ijk->ik',df.values.reshape(-1,2,df.shape[1]))/2.0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 266 µs per loop
```

Comment: This one is ~2x faster than groupby. Nice.

Comment: @ayhan Yeah I noticed that, was about to post runtimes, but then final thought was to let it pass :) Yours is a new thing I learned though, pandas not being my thing!

Comment: Note that your numpy approaches lose the column names.  You could add `columns=df.columns` to correct this.

Comment: @DSM Yeah, totally missed that! Thanks! Added that as a note.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.set_index(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).mean(level=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, as you want to average the rows, assuming your dataframe name is `new`

```
new = new.groupby(np.arange(len(new)) // 2).mean()
```

If one wants to do the average for the columns

```
new = new.groupby(np.arrange(len(new.columns)) // 2, axis=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length` when I tried using `numpy` to create the artificial group. As an alternative, you can use `itertools` which will generate an iterator of equal length to your Dataframe:

```
SAMPLE_SIZE = 2
label_series = pd.Series(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, SAMPLE_SIZE) for x in df.index))
sampled_df = df.groupby(label_series).mean()
```