# How to speed up groupby().sum() on a dask dataframe with 5 millions of rows and 500 thousands of groups?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with

- 5 millions of rows.
- a column `group_id` whose number of unique elements is 500.000.
- thousands of other columns named `var1`, `var2`, etc. Each of `var1`, `var2`, ... contains only 0 and 1.

I would like to group by `group_id` and then sum them up. To have better performance, I use dask. However, the speed is still slow for this simple aggregation.

```
The time spent on a dataframe with 10 columns is 6.285385847091675 seconds
The time spent on a dataframe with 100 columns is 64.9060411453247 seconds
The time spent on a dataframe with 200 columns is 150.6109869480133 seconds
The time spent on a dataframe with 300 columns is 235.77087807655334 seconds
```

My real dataset contains up to 30.000 columns. I have read answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143717/groupby-in-python-pandas-fast-way) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053734/improving-the-performance-of-repetitive-groupby-operations)) by @Divakar about using numpy. However, the former thread is about counting and the latter is about summing columns.

Could you please elaborate on some ways to speed up this aggregation?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, time
from multiprocessing import dummy
import dask.dataframe as dd

core = os.cpu_count()
P = dummy.Pool(processes = core)

n_docs = 500000
n_rows = n_docs * 10
data = {}

def create_col(i):
    name = 'var' + str(i)
    data[name] = np.random.randint(0, 2, n_rows)

n_cols = 300
P.map(create_col, range(1, n_cols + 1))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype = 'int8')
df.insert(0, 'group_id', np.random.randint(1, n_docs + 1, n_rows))
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 3 * core) 

start = time.time()
df.groupby('group_id').sum().compute()
end = time.time()
print('The time spent on a dataframe with {} columns is'.format(n_cols), end - start, 'seconds')
```

Comment: Where is the real dataset going to come from?

Comment: @JeffUK It is generated by applying `pd.get_dummies` on an original dataframe with 25 columns.

Comment: group_id comes from 0 up to 499999?

Comment: @dankal444 it ranges from 1 to 500.000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I misunderstood OP in original answer, so clearing all).

I got improvement by:

- switching to numpy
- using same dtype for group and data (np.int32)
- using numba with parallel mode'

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit('int32[:, :](int32[:, :], int_)', parallel=True)
def count_groups2(group_and_data, n_groups):
    n_cols = group_and_data.shape[1] - 1
    counts = np.zeros((n_groups, n_cols), dtype=np.int32)
    for idx in nb.prange(len(group_and_data)):
        row = group_and_data[idx]
        counts[row[0]] += row[1:]
    return counts

df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype='int32')
group_id = np.random.randint(1, n_docs + 1, n_rows, dtype=np.int32)
df.insert(0, 'group_id', group_id)

# switching to numpy (line below) is costly
# it would be faster to work with numpy alone (no pandas)
group_and_data = df.values
count_groups2(group_and_data)
op_method(df)
```

```
    72         1    1439807.0 1439807.0      7.0      group_and_data = df.values
    73         1    1341527.0 1341527.0      6.5      count_groups2(group_and_data, n_groups=500_000)
    74         1   12043334.0 12043334.0     58.5      op_method(df)
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! In your code, there is a loop `for idx in range(len(group_ids))`. My computer has 28 cores and 56 threads. Is there any modification to parallel `for idx in range(len(group_ids))`?

Comment: From the line `sums = df_values[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)`, I think you misunderstood my goal :) I mean to sum rows that belong to the same group, not to sum columns.

Comment: @Akura I edited and added parallelism, but it gives some significant boost only when using numpy arrays instead of dataframes.

Comment: @Akira You mean you count them? Or maybe for each group you want to have sum for each column?

Comment: Exactly, I want to have sum of all rows for each column.

Comment: @Akira I fixed the answer, take a look

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So you have run 3 versions `op_method(df)`, `faster4(group_and_data)`, and `group_and_data = df.values` and mentioned that *switching to numpy (line below) is costly, it would be faster to work with numpy alone (no pandas)*. I understand that `op_method(df)` is my original code. Can you explain what is the difference between 2 versions `faster4(group_and_data)` and `group_and_data = df.values`?

Comment: I have run your updated code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cdmjnGWgQcpwyzRsbMgT6Bb7h4F9Bt8K?usp=sharing), but it returns an error :(( Could you please include the full code of the fastest version `faster4(group_and_data)`?

Comment: @Akira sorry, faster4 was just old name I forgot to change, I guess you already got it working but updated answer anyway

Comment: May I ask what is the inumber `7.0` in the line `72         1    1439807.0 1439807.0      7.0      group_and_data = df.values`?

Comment: @Akira Its percent of time this line took in a profiled function. I use `line_profiler` that gives results in such a form: `Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents`

Comment: Applying your code to my real dataset reduced the computation time from 1h 20min 54s to just 7min 22s. My CPU with 28 cores and 56 threads are [fully utilized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEe6X.png). This is very impressive. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you for letting me know :)