# Pandas resample data frame with fixed number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

With [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) I can downsample a DataFrame into a certain time duration:

```
df.resample("3s").mean()
```

However, I do not want to specify a certain time, but rather a fixed number of rows in the original data frame, e.g. "resample such that three rows previously are now aggregated into one". How's that possible in pandas?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table/36810658#36810658

Comment: Do you need `df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3).mean()` ?

Comment: @jezrael: I was hoping for sth. more idiomatic, less hacky.

Comment: @knub, AFAIK the solution proposed by ayhan and jezrael is currently the most idiomatic way to achieve that what you want

Comment: I mostly use MultiIndexes in similar situations. I keep one index equivalent of `np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3` and then group using that level (i.e. `df.groupby(level=something)`) But other than that, I don't believe pandas offers a built in method to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a bit late, but here is my answer for everyone searching for a solution to this problem.

One solution would be to use pandas [rolling(n)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) sliding window functionality and then select every nth value. e.G. for n=3

```
df_sub = df.rolling(3).mean()[::3]
```

this is a bit wasteful for calculation, since you recalculate the whole dataframe and then just keep 1/n percent of it.

Another similar approach to the problem, wich is not calculating the mean, but instead interpolating the whole dataframe column wise would be to use numpy's [interp1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function.

e.G.: Assuming you have a DataFrame, where the indices are are monotonically increasing numerical/timestamped values (as usually with time series data), and you want to adjust every column individually you could do it like this:

```
def resample_fixed(df, n_new):
    n_old, m = df.values.shape
    mat_old = df.values
    mat_new = np.zeros((n_new, m))
    x_old = np.linspace(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), n_old)
    x_new = np.linspace(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), n_new)

    for j in range(m):
        y_old = mat_old[:, j]
        y_new = np.interp(x_new, x_old, y_old)
        mat_new[:, j] = y_new

    return pd.DataFrame(mat_new, index=x_new, columns=df.columns)
```

be careful though, interp1 does alter your data, since it linearly interpolates your datapoints. I would recommend inspecting the result after interpolation.

You can find a full example on the interpolation in a gist file I did for that [here](https://gist.github.com/TobiasGlaubach/68298acdd637860f115c83ff439ac8b7).