# epoching time series data in python - How we can create window based on the time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have time-series data. 7200 rows(data point) and two columns (one time and one frequency data). I want to calculate the average of the frequencies for every 120 rows. I wrote the following code. I know it is very stupid, but I don't want to repeat the following code for 60 times. Is there any way in which I can do it automatically or shorter?

Thank you for your help

```
window1 = df1[['p1', 'p2']].iloc[0:119].mean(axis=0)
window2 = df1[['p1', 'p2']].iloc[120:239].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate average of every x rows in a table and create new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) functionality?