# Python: I need to find the average over x amount of rows in a specific column of a large csv file

Tags: pandas

I have a large CSV file with two columns in it as shown below:

[image]

I have already filtered the data. I need to calculate the average pressure every x amount  of rows.

I've looked for a while on here but was unable to find how to calculate the average every x amount of rows for a specific column. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate average of every x rows in a table and create new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy - [average](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) & [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
n = 3
x = df['Pressure']
  
# calculates the average
avgResult = np.average(givenArray.reshape(-1, n), axis=1)
```

the result is array, which divide columns into n sets:

eg:

```
array([3.33333333, 4.66666667])
```

in:

```
n=3
x = np.array([1, 4, 5,2,8,4])
```