# How do you find the average of a column over a certain number of rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So basically I have to find the average for the first 168 values in the dataframe, then the next 168 and so on until the dataframe ends.

Comment: [Calculate average of every x rows in a table and create new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table)

Comment: if you want the window centered on the left: `df.iloc[::-1].rolling(168).mean().iloc[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
results = []
idx = 168
while 168*(i+1) < len(df):
    temp = df.iloc[168*i:168*(i+1)].mean()
    results.append(mean)
```