# Why am I getting this output when running function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to calculate the mean value of the last numbers of this measurements(those belonging to the same batch/first number)

```
1,  73
1,  101
2,  17
2,  23
```

for example I want my code to return 2 mean values for the values above(desired output):

```
1    87.0.       #(73+101)/2
2    20.0        #(17+23)/2
```

But somehow my code is only returning one value, can't really find the problem, would be appreciated if someone can tell me what the problem is! this is my code!

```
def collect_exp_data(file_name):
    data = dict()
    with open(file_name, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
            batch, x, y, value = line.split(',')
            print(batch)
            if not batch in data:
                data[batch] = []
            data[batch] += [(float(x),float(y),float(value))]
    return data
    
def value_average(dict):
    for batch, sample in dict.items():
        average_list_length = 0
        average_list_sum = 0
        for x,y,value in sample: 
            if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
                average_list_sum += value
                average_list_length += 1
        average = average_list_sum/average_list_length
        return batch, average 
   
for batch, sample in collect_exp_data("/Users/../Desktop/sample1.txt").items():          
            print(value_average(collect_exp_data("/Users/../Desktop/sample1.txt")))
```

this is what im getting back

```
('1', 87.0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table
it may help you

Comment: Unfortunately it did not since i'm trying to write the code by myself without using imports!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running the main loop twice, first in the end of the file with `for batch, sample in collect_exp_data(...` and second time in `value_average` function. Only one of these is required. Here is a modified example which produces a dictionary with your requested values:

```
def value_average(data):
    return_dict = {}
    for batch, sample in data.items():
        average_list_length = 0
        average_list_sum = 0
        for x, y, value in sample: 
            if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
                average_list_sum += value
                average_list_length += 1
        average = average_list_sum/average_list_length
        return_dict[batch] = average
    return return_dict

print(value_average(collect_exp_data("/Users/../Desktop/sample1.txt")))
```

Also, refrain from using `dict`, `list` or other built-in python types as a variable name, it will most likely mess some code up later on and is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you your answer! Your feedback helps very much since im a beginner and trying to improve my code as much as I can! Can you maybe spot other things that I can improve so the code becomes easier to read and understand? Maybe unnecessary steps in the code?

Comment: @PatrickArtner My bad, I'll modify the answer. You're absolutely right it works as is and the loop implementation was the issue.