# Swapping Columns with NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterable-unpacking

When I have `a=1` and `b=2`, I can write `a,b=b,a` so that `a` and `b` are interchanged with each other.

I use this matrix as an array:

```
   [ 1,  2,  0, -2]
   [ 0,  0,  1,  2]
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0]
```

Swapping the columns of a numpy array does not work:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[ 1,  2,  0, -2],
   [ 0,  0,  1,  2],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])

x[:,1], x[:,2] = x[:,2], x[:,1]
```

It yields:

```
   [ 1,  0,  0, -2]
   [ 0,  1,  1,  2]
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0]
```

So `x[:,1]` has simply been overwritten and not transferred to `x[:,2]`.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Good question. It works as expected with regular lists, e.g. `d = [0,1,2,3]; d[:2], d[2:] = d[2:], d[:2]` yields `[2, 3, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're trying to swap columns you can do it by

```
print x
x[:,[2,1]] = x[:,[1,2]]
print x
```

**output**

```
[[ 1  2  0 -2]
 [ 0  0  1  2]
 [ 0  0  0  0]]
[[ 1  0  2 -2]
 [ 0  1  0  2]
 [ 0  0  0  0]]
```

The swapping method you mentioned in the question seems to be working for single dimensional arrays and lists though,

```
x =  np.array([1,2,0,-2])
print x
x[2], x[1] = x[1], x[2]
print x
```

**output**

```
[ 1  2  0 -2] 
[ 1  0  2 -2]
```

Answer (score 15):

When you use the `x[:] = y[:]` syntax with a numpy array, the values of y are copied directly into x; no temporaries are made. So when you do `x[:, 1], x[:,2] = x[:, 2], x[:, 1]`, first the third column of x is copied directly into the second column, and then the second column is copied directly into the third.

The second column has already been overwritten by the third columns values by the time you copy the second column to the third, so you end up with the original values in the third column.

Numpy is designed to avoid copies where possible in order to improve performance. It's important to understand that `list[:]` returns a copy of the list, while `np.array[:]` returns a [view of the numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array).

Answer (score 1):

if you need to swap the mth and the nth rows, you could you the following code:

```
temp = a[m,:].copy()
a[m,:]  = a[n,:]
a[n,:] =  temp
```

you can extrapolate the same concept for swapping the columns by changing the indices.

Answer (score 0):

**can you try something like:**

```
arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)

arr[:, [1,0]]

array([[1, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [5, 4],
       [7, 6],
       [9, 8]])
```

Comment: Works, but pay attention that this is just a view, not a copy.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution would be to use swapaxes

```
x = x.swapaxes(1,2)
```

Comment: Wrong, this does not swap *columns*, it's "sort of" a transposition.
```arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
print(np.array_equal(arr.swapaxes(0, 1), arr.T))```