# Numpy: using entries of array to populate larger array with repeats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can the following be done without loops?

```py
B = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],[1, 0, 3, 5],[2, 3, 0, 6],[3, 5, 6, 0]])
mylist = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0] #note the repeats

BigB = np.zeros((len(mylist),len(mylist)),np.int64)

for i,row in enumerate(mylist):
    for j,col in enumerate(mylist):
        BigB[i,j] = B[row,col]
```

Output

```
B
Out[100]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])

BigB
Out[101]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 0, 6, 2],
       [3, 5, 3, 6, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0]])
```

If there were no repeats, I could use direct indexing as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438098/permute-rows-and-columns-of-a-matrix)

Comment: Can you elaborate what is to be achieved?

Comment: Exactly what the loops do. `BigB[i,j] = B[mylist[i],mylist[j]]` with `0< i,j < len(mylist)`

Comment: Thanks @divakar 
For reference, the answer is `BigB = B[np.ix_(mylist,mylist)]`