# Swap/Transpose matrix columns

Tags: python, matrix, swap

I have a 2d array like this:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

And I want to swap the first and second columns, which would look like this:

```
[2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 6]
[8, 7, 9]
```

I've looked around, but all I can find is stuff about turning rows into columns. I tried the `zip` function for example, but again it just does this:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Using numpy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507550/swapping-columns-with-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for i in m:
    i[0],i[1] = i[1],i[0]
```

output

```
[[2, 1, 3], 
[5, 4, 6], 
[8, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: This does not work. It will get you -  >>> m
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]

Comment: @thank you for correcting me, I read the question as the first column and last column. Again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you just want the first and second columns swapped you should change the code to be something like this:

```
for i in m:
    i[1],i[0] = i[0],i[1]
```

Comment: This works fine  - each row is just a sublist, and want to swap first, second item - which is  `[1]` and [0]`.  However, it is more nature to write this way: for i in m:
 i[0], i[1] = i[1], i[0]