# Numpy Arrays: Extracting preferentially ordered values from array with Nans without padding?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

Suppose I have an array (M,N) where the values in each "column", N, represent data recordings of N different machines. Let's also imagine each "row", M, represents a unique "timestamp" where data was recorded for all of the N machines.

The array (M,N) is structured in a way so that at M = 0, this would corresp[ond to the very first "timestamp" (t0) and the row M = M (tm) represents the most recent "timestamp" recording.

Let's call this array "AX." AX[0] would yield the recorded data for N machines at the very 1st "timestamp". AX[-1] would be the most recent recordings.

Here is my array:

```
>>AX = np.random.randn(3, 5)

array([[ 0.53826804, -0.9450442 , -0.10279278,  0.47251871,  0.32050493],
       [-0.97573464, -0.42359652, -0.00223274,  0.7364234 ,  0.83810714],
       [-0.07626913,  0.85246932, -0.13736392, -1.39977431, -1.39882156]])
```

Now imagine something went wrong and data wasn't captured consistently for every machine at every "timestamp". To create an example of what the output might look like I followed the example linked below to insert Nans in random positions in the array:

[Create sample numpy array with randomly placed NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182409/create-sample-numpy-array-with-randomly-placed-nans)

```
>>AX.ravel()[np.random.choice(AX.size, 9, replace=False)] = np.nan


array([[ 0.53826804, -0.9450442 ,         nan,  0.47251871,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.7364234 ,  0.83810714],
       [-0.07626913,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

Let's assume that I need to provide the most recent values of the recorded data. Ideally this would be as easy as referencing AX[-1]. In this particular case, I would hardly have any data since everything got screwed up.

```
>>AX[-1]

array([-0.07626913,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan])
```

**GOAL**:

I realize any data is better than nothing, so I would like use the **most recent** value recorded for each machine. In this particular scenario, the best I could is provide an array with the values:

```
[-0.07626913, -0.9450442, 0.7364234, 0.83810714]
```

Notice column 2 of AX had no usable data, so I just skipped it's ouput.

I do not find np.arrays to be very intuitive and as I read through the documentation, I am overwhelmed by the amount of specialized functions and transforms.

My intial idea was to perhaps filter out all of the Nans to a new array (AY), and then take the last row AY[-1] (assuming this would retains its important row based ordering) Then I realized that this would be making an array with a strange shape of (I'm just using integer values here for convenience instead of AX's values):

```
[1,2,3],
[4,5],
[6]
```

Assuming that is even possible to create, taking the last "row"(?) would yield [6,5,3] and would totally mess everything up. Padding an array with values is also bad because the most recent values would be pads for 4 out of 5 data points in the most recent "timestamp" row.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in a fairly painless manner while still using the np.array stucture and avoiding dataframes and panels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of question that can generate many interesting answers.  Someone will probably come up with a better way than this, but to get things started, here's one possibility:

```
In [99]: AX
Out[99]: 
array([[ 0.53826804, -0.9450442 ,         nan,  0.47251871,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.7364234 ,  0.83810714],
       [-0.07626913,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

`np.isfinite(AX)` is a boolean array that is True where `AX` is not nan (and not infinite, but I assume that case is not relevant).  For a boolean array `B`, `B.argmax(axis=0)` gives the indices of the *first* True value in each column.  To get the indices of the *last* True value, reverse the array, take the argmax, and then subtract the result from the number of rows minus 1; that is, `B.shape[0]-1 - B[::-1].argmax(axis=0)`.  In this case, `B` is `np.isfinite(AX)`, so we have:

```
In [100]: k = AX.shape[0] - 1 - np.isfinite(AX)[::-1].argmax(axis=0)
```

`k` contains the row indices where the final values occur.  There is one for each column, so the corresponding column indices are simply `np.arange(AX.shape[1])`.

```
In [101]: last_vals = AX[k, np.arange(AX.shape[1])]
```

`last_vals` is the one-dimensional array of the last non-nan values in each column, unless a column is all nan, in which case the value in `last_vals` is also nan:

```
In [102]: last_vals
Out[102]: array([-0.07626913, -0.9450442 ,         nan,  0.7364234 ,  0.83810714])
```

To eliminate the non-nan values in `last_vals`, you can index it with `np.isfinite(last_vals)`:

```
In [103]: last_vals[np.isfinite(last_vals)]
Out[103]: array([-0.07626913, -0.9450442 ,  0.7364234 ,  0.83810714])
```

Comment: This seems real ingenious! I'm gonna slowly walk myself through your steps manually to make sure I understand each part. There's a lot going on here :)

Comment: I appreciate the "accept", but it was probably too soon.  There are quite a few clever numpythonistas who keep an eye on the stackoverflow questions, and you are more likely to get a variety of answers if you wait awhile before accepting one.

Comment: Well shucks, I'm pretty new to this site and didn't realize that was the motivation for getting responses. Do people continue to comment on accepted answers?

Comment: Yes, they do.  There is nothing wrong with accepting it, but some folks might not look too closely at a question if there is already an accepted answer.  Waiting a day or so is probably a good idea.  In this case, I feel like there's something that could be done to make this even simpler or more efficient, so I wouldn't mind seeing more answers myself.

Comment: Yet, you did respond first with a working solution which was exactly what I was hoping for. Perhaps the nature of the question will entice the numpythonistas to bedazzle us with their solutions regardless of the question status? Or should I undo the accept(if possible) and fish for more? Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Well, I will undo it then just to see what happens, but to me, you win for even helping me tackle it and with such alacrity.