# combining features of 'array of objects' with 'object of arrays'

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, numpy

I'm looking for some sort of paradigm or implementation to efficiently handle many sets of coupled N-dim arrays (`ndarray`s).  Specifically, I'm hoping for an implementation that allows me to slice an array of entire objects (e.g. `someObjs = objects[100:200]`), or individual attributes of those objects (e.g. `somePars1 = objects.par1[100:200]`) --- at the same time.

To expand on the above example, I could construct the following subsets in two ways:

```
def subset1(objects, beg, end):
    pars1 = [ obj.par1 for obj in objects[beg:end] ]
    pars2 = [ obj.par2 for obj in objects[beg:end] ]
    return pars1, pars2

def subset2(objects, beg, end):
    pars1 = objects.par1[beg:end]
    pars2 = objects.par2[beg:end]
    return pars1, pars2
```

And they would be identical.

---

Edit:

One approach would be to override the `__getitem__` (etc) methods, something like,

```
class Objects(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.par1 = p1
        self.par2 = p2
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Objects(self.p1[key], self.p2[key])
```

But this is horribly inefficient, and it duplicates the subset.  Perhaps there's someway to return a `view` of the subset??

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are you trying to find a language that allows you to place the index in either position?  This is antithetical to the structure of most languages.  If you have a list of objects, the subscript expression *must* be applied directly to the list, not to the element.  Your code is correct either way, depending on how you design your objects.  However, you cannot have this dual nature in a language that honours type characteristics.

Comment: @Prune, I don't think that is the case.  See the example I added.  Achieving this functionality is certainly possible  --- but I can't think of any way of doing it effectively/efficiently.

Comment: I understand now; thanks.  Do keep in mind that this is inherently inefficient: you're accepting the natural structure, but then overlaying an artificial structure on that.  Every reference to the artificial structure -- the view that you want -- requires dismantling and rearranging elements of the "correct" organization.

However, a view pattern would likely be the way to go for maintainability.  I don't know whether this tells you anything new; I'm likely just reinforcing what you feared.

Comment: @Prune, sure - thanks.  It definitely might be a lost-cause, but perhaps there's something not ***too*** inefficient.

Comment: I think this can be a good approach, actually. One thing to keep in mind is that slicing of numpy arrays always returns a view (as long as you use a slice and not "fancy indexing" with a list/tuple).  Therefore, your example actually doesn't duplicate that much memory at all, provided you enforce contiguous slices.  However, the usual caveats with sharing views apply: If you modify one, you're modifying all and you need to be aware of what makes copies and what doesn't when using things.

Comment: @JoeKington thanks!  Can you give (or point me towards) more information on assuring that I only use views instead of duplication?  I think that would be enough for an `answer`.

Comment: The numpy documentation goes over it in quite a bit of detail: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing  Not to plug one of my own answers too much, but you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array/4371049#4371049  It specifically deals with how to avoid copies and ensure views.  I'm too short on time at the moment for a full answer, so if someone wants to condense things and write one up, please feel free!

Answer (score 2):

**Object array and object with array approach**

A sample object class

```
In [56]: class MyObj(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self, par1,par2):
   ....:         self.par1=par1
   ....:         self.par2=par2
```

An array of those objects - little more than a list with an array wrapper

```
In [57]: objects=np.array([MyObj(1,2),MyObj(3,4),MyObj(2,3),MyObj(10,11)])
In [58]: objects
Out[58]: 
array([<__main__.MyObj object at 0xb31b196c>,
       <__main__.MyObj object at 0xb31b116c>,
       <__main__.MyObj object at 0xb31b13cc>,
       <__main__.MyObj object at 0xb31b130c>], dtype=object)
```

`subset`` type of selection:

```
In [59]: [obj.par1 for obj in objects[1:-1]]
Out[59]: [3, 2]
```

Another class that can contain such an array.  This is simpler than defining an array subclass:

```
In [60]: class MyObjs(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self,anArray):
   ....:         self.data=anArray
   ....:     def par1(self):
   ....:         return [obj.par1 for obj in self.data]

In [61]: Obs = MyObjs(objects)
In [62]: Obs.par1()
Out[62]: [1, 3, 2, 10]
```

`subset2` type of selection:

```
In [63]: Obs.par1()[1:-1]
Out[63]: [3, 2]
```

For now `par1` is a method, but could made a property, permitting `Obs.par1[1:-1]` syntax.

If `par1` returned an array instead of a list, indexing would be more powerful.

If `MyObjs` had a `__getitem__` method, then it could be indexed with

```
Obs[1:-1]
```

That method could be defined in various ways, though the simplest is to apply the indexing 'slice' to the 'data':

```
def __getitem__(self, *args):
    # not tested
    return MyObjs(self.data.__getitem(*args))
```

I'm focusing just on syntax, not on efficiency.  In general numpy arrays of general objects is not very fast or powerful.  Such arrays are basically lists of pointers to the objects.

**Structured array and recarray version**

Another possiblity is `np.recarray`.  Another poster was just asking about their names.  They essentially are structured array where fields can be accessed as attributes.

With a structured array definition:

```
In [64]: dt = np.dtype([('par1', int), ('par2', int)])
In [66]: Obj1 = np.array([(1,2),(3,4),(2,3),(10,11)], dtype=dt)
In [67]: Obj1
Out[67]: 
array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3), (10, 11)], 
      dtype=[('par1', '<i4'), ('par2', '<i4')])
In [68]: Obj1['par1'][1:-1]
Out[68]: array([3, 2])
In [69]: Obj1[1:-1]['par1']
Out[69]: array([3, 2])
```

or as recarray

```
In [79]: Objrec=np.rec.fromrecords(Obj1,dtype=dt)
In [80]: Objrec.par1
Out[80]: array([ 1,  3,  2, 10])
In [81]: Objrec.par1[1:-1]
Out[81]: array([3, 2])
In [82]: Objrec[1:-1].par1
Out[82]: array([3, 2])
```

Comment: The `recarray`  solution looks fantastic!  I'll need to play with this a little, but I think that'll be perfect.  Thanks so much!