# How does frompyfunc iterate over arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with large arrays representing a maze routing grid, each element is a Cell object with x,y attributes.

I am trying to use numpyfunc to initialize the coordinates in each cell with a vectorized function.

I have a vectorized function that sets the X coordinate of a Cell object:

```
def setCellX(self,c,x):
         c.setX(x)
         return c

setCellX_v = np.vectorize(self.setCellX)
```

I wrap this in frompyfunc

```
setCellX_npfunc = np.frompyfunc(self.setCellX_v,2,1)
```

When I call this on a 1-D array, it works as expected

```
Gx = 3000
Gy = 4000

# Initialize single row
R = np.array([Cell(0,y) for y in range(int(self.Gy))])

# Create array of X-coordinates
x_indices = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]

print R[6].x
0

setCellX_npfunc(R,x_indices)
print R[6].x
6
```

When I set R to be a 2-D array, I would expect for numpyfunc to iterate over each row and set the X values accordingly:

```
R = np.empty(shape=(20,20),dtype=object)
R.fill(Cell(0,0))

setCellX_npfunc(R,x_indices)
print(R[3][6].x)
19
```

Why wouldn't numpyfunc set the X values for each 1-d vector to the corresponding value in x_indices, like it did in the first example?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want the matrix to be like in the end? It is confusing what you're trying to do. Also another advice, `np.vectorize` does not actually confer a speed benefit to your function, it just hides the iteration.

Comment: In the end, I need a matrix G of Cell objects.  So, G[0,0].x = 0 and G[123,456].x = 123.  Similarly, G[123][456].y = 456.  I'm not sure of the best or most efficient way to build the array.

Comment: So your cell will have `x` and `y` attribute along with some other attribute that we don't need to care about right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: `frompyfunc` passes 'scalar' values to your function, not arrays or rows of arrays.  Same for `vectorize`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and suppose that `Cell` objects have `x, y` attributes and some other default attribute that doesn't come to play:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    ...
```

Suppose you want a 100*100 array, initiate your array like this:

```
CellList = [[Cell(x,y) for y in range(100)] for x in range(100)]
# Optional translate it into np.array for easier indexing
CellArr = np.array(CellList)
```

This will return your 100*100 Cell array that has correct Cell elements. To verify:

```
CellArr[1,2].x
>>> 1
```

Note that `numpy` can't actually speed up your array much because `Cell` cannot actually go through C code when vectorizing. It could only be used for better indexing.

Vectorizing does not actually help your speed:

```
%%timeit
CellList = [[Cell(x,y) for y in range(100)] for x in range(100)]
# Optional translate it into np.array for easier indexing
CellArr = np.array(CellList)

>>> 24.2 ms ± 542 µs per loop
```

Vectorizing functions:

```
def vecX(c, x):
    c = Cell(x, 0)
    return c

def vecY(c, y):
    c.y = y
    return c

vec = np.vectorize(vecX)
vey = np.vectorize(vecY)
```

results:

```
%%timeit
l = []
n = np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range(len(n)):
    l.append(vec(n[i, :], i))
CellArr = np.vstack(l)
for j in range(len(CellArr)):
    vey(CellArr[:, j], j)

>>> 23.5 ms ± 5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes, that would work.  I run into issues when I have arrays of 3000x4000 or something along those lines, I'm wondering if there's a faster way in those cases to make the array?  In these cases I can make large vectors of coordinates (say 1x4000), but iterating through each element is slow.  Is there a way to apply a vector to another vector, i.e set the x values for each Cell at G[200] to x=200.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running out of memory? All of these references will have to live in your memory and they will take up an incredible amount of space - in fact, if there are any function that lives in your `Cell` class you might want to take them out and do numeric calculations instead - which *is vectorizable*

Comment: I tried vectorizing and it confers no speed benefits - I'll post the results. Which is expected because if you vectorize a python function it would just hide the iteration wrapper.