# Writing a numpy.array() from a list of namedtuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, namedtuple

I have a list of namedtuples which I would like to write to a numpy array.
The tuples have attributes 'colors', a set of two colors, and 'number', an integer, and are of the form:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

NamedTuple = namedtuple('tuple',['colors','number'])

L = [NamedTuple({'violet', 'blue'}, 4),  
    NamedTuple({'orange', 'blue'}, 1),  
    NamedTuple({'green', 'blue'}, 3),  
    NamedTuple({'orange', 'red'}, 2)]
L
>>>[tuple(colors={'blue', 'violet'}, number=4)...]
L[3].colors
>>>{'orange', 'red'}
```

I would like to write from L, for example, a 2x2 array such that:

```
Array[1][1].colors
>>>{'orange', 'red'}
```

Doing

```
Array = numpy.array(L)
>>>[[{'blue', 'violet'} 4]
   [{'blue', 'orange'} 1]
   [{'blue', 'green'} 3]
   [{'red', 'orange'} 2]
```

gives me an array of tuples, not namedtuples, which have 'no attribute 'colors''
Worse yet, if I try to reshape Array into a 2x2 I find out that each attribute of my namedtuples has been written as a different object in the array.

```
numpy.reshape(Array,(2,2))
>>>...error...
>>>'ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (2,2)'
```

I would have thought the above array was size 4?

How can I get an array of namedtuples without mutating the namedtuples, such that I can call for different attributes from each element in the array?

The reason I would like to use namedtuples as my data structure is so it is easy and readable to call each object's .color or .number attribute.
The reason I would like to use a numpy array rather than a standard nested list is because this array is going to be a dynamic object throughout the project which will often be searched through and changed, and I know how poor python's standard lists are for these things.
For context, I am ultimately trying to build a program which plays a card game of my own invention. The namedtuples represent the cards with their colors and numbers. The Array represents a tableau of cards which players can change and move around. These namedtuples are going to be shuffled around quite a bit and I don't want to have to worry about their data structures getting changed.

Answer (score 2):

Becauuse `NamedTuple` is a subclass of `tuple`, constructing an object array from `L` results in a (n,2) array, same as if we given it as list of tuples or list of lists:

```
In [4]: np.array(L, object)
Out[4]: 
array([[{'violet', 'blue'}, 4],
       [{'blue', 'orange'}, 1],
       [{'blue', 'green'}, 3],
       [{'red', 'orange'}, 2]], dtype=object)
In [5]: _.shape
Out[5]: (4, 2)
```

Here's one trick - append a `None` object to the list, first:

```
In [13]: arr = np.array(L+[None], object)[:-1]
In [14]: arr
Out[14]: 
array([tuple(colors={'violet', 'blue'}, number=4),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'orange'}, number=1),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'green'}, number=3),
       tuple(colors={'red', 'orange'}, number=2)], dtype=object)
In [15]: arr.shape
Out[15]: (4,)
In [16]: arr = np.reshape(arr,(2,2))
In [17]: arr
Out[17]: 
array([[tuple(colors={'violet', 'blue'}, number=4),
        tuple(colors={'blue', 'orange'}, number=1)],
       [tuple(colors={'blue', 'green'}, number=3),
        tuple(colors={'red', 'orange'}, number=2)]], dtype=object)
```

I've found in previous questions that `frompyfunc` is the most convenient tool (and fastest) for accessing elements of such an array.

[Most efficient way to set attributes on objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034280/most-efficient-way-to-set-attributes-on-objects-in-array)

```
In [18]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.colors, 1,1)(arr)
Out[18]: 
array([[{'violet', 'blue'}, {'blue', 'orange'}],
       [{'blue', 'green'}, {'red', 'orange'}]], dtype=object)
```

---

To construct a structured array, we can do:

```
In [19]: arr1 = np.array(L, dtype=[('colors', object), ('number', int)])
In [20]: arr1
Out[20]: 
array([({'violet', 'blue'}, 4), ({'blue', 'orange'}, 1),
       ({'blue', 'green'}, 3), ({'red', 'orange'}, 2)],
      dtype=[('colors', 'O'), ('number', '<i8')])
```

`NamedTuple` is a subclass of `tuple`, so it works as data input (e.g. list of tuples).

```
In [22]: arr1['colors']
Out[22]: 
array([{'violet', 'blue'}, {'blue', 'orange'}, {'blue', 'green'},
       {'red', 'orange'}], dtype=object)
In [23]: arr1['number']
Out[23]: array([4, 1, 3, 2])
```

---

Initializing an 1d array and assigning elements works:

```
In [30]: arr2 = np.empty(4, object)
In [31]: arr2[:] = L
In [32]: arr2
Out[32]: 
array([tuple(colors={'violet', 'blue'}, number=4),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'orange'}, number=1),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'green'}, number=3),
       tuple(colors={'red', 'orange'}, number=2)], dtype=object)
```

Filling a `np.empty((2,2), object)` will be a bit trickier.

---

I can construct an object array from the fields of the structured array (or any other pair of lists of inputs) with:

```
In [44]: np.frompyfunc(NamedTuple, 2,1)(arr1['colors'], arr1['number'])
Out[44]: 
array([tuple(colors={'violet', 'blue'}, number=4),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'orange'}, number=1),
       tuple(colors={'blue', 'green'}, number=3),
       tuple(colors={'red', 'orange'}, number=2)], dtype=object)
```