# Numpy: would vstack automatically detect an index is out of range and correct it?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm puzzled as to why the in the code below (the section where I labeled "HERE"), would work because j+1 would make the list of list (which is the X_train_folds) go out of range when j reaches the end of the range. Why would this even work? Is it because vstack can automatically detect this change? I couldn't find any documentation for it though.

```
num_folds = 5
k_choices = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 50, 100]

X_train_folds = []
y_train_folds = []
################################################################################
# Split up the training data into folds. After splitting, X_train_folds and    #
# y_train_folds should each be lists of length num_folds, where                #
# y_train_folds[i] is the label vector for the points in X_train_folds[i].     #
# Hint: Look up the numpy array_split function.                                #
################################################################################
X_train_folds = np.array_split(X_train, num_folds)
y_train_folds = np.array_split(y_train, num_folds)

# print y_train_folds

# A dictionary holding the accuracies for different values of k that we find
# when running cross-validation. After running cross-validation,
# k_to_accuracies[k] should be a list of length num_folds giving the different
# accuracy values that we found when using that value of k.
k_to_accuracies = {}

################################################################################
# Perform k-fold cross validation to find the best value of k. For each        #
# possible value of k, run the k-nearest-neighbor algorithm num_folds times,   #
# where in each case you use all but one of the folds as training data and the #
# last fold as a validation set. Store the accuracies for all fold and all     #
# values of k in the k_to_accuracies dictionary.                               #
################################################################################

for k in k_choices:
    k_to_accuracies[k] = []

for k in k_choices:
    print 'evaluating k=%d' % k
    for j in range(num_folds):
        X_train_cv = np.vstack(X_train_folds[0:j]+X_train_folds[j+1:])#<--------------HERE
        X_test_cv = X_train_folds[j]

        #print len(y_train_folds), y_train_folds[0].shape

        y_train_cv = np.hstack(y_train_folds[0:j]+y_train_folds[j+1:]) #<----------------HERE
        y_test_cv = y_train_folds[j]

        #print 'Training data shape: ', X_train_cv.shape
        #print 'Training labels shape: ', y_train_cv.shape
        #print 'Test data shape: ', X_test_cv.shape
        #print 'Test labels shape: ', y_test_cv.shape

        classifier.train(X_train_cv, y_train_cv)
        dists_cv = classifier.compute_distances_no_loops(X_test_cv)
        #print 'predicting now'
        y_test_pred = classifier.predict_labels(dists_cv, k)
        num_correct = np.sum(y_test_pred == y_test_cv)
        accuracy = float(num_correct) / num_test

        k_to_accuracies[k].append(accuracy)

################################################################################
#                                 END OF YOUR CODE                             #
################################################################################

# Print out the computed accuracies
for k in sorted(k_to_accuracies):
    for accuracy in k_to_accuracies[k]:
        print 'k = %d, accuracy = %f' % (k, accuracy)
```

Comment: What are `X_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: It's because you are using slices.  `np.arange(5)[:10]` is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `vstack` is not causing that, but the very powerful [indexation of numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) is. The internals of numpy are complex and sometimes it returns a copy, other times a [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array). In both cases, however, you are launching methods. And this method in particular returns an `empty array` when indexation is, itself, empty (as outside the space of the array).

See the following example and the consequential outputs (in `print`):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a[10:]) # This will return empty
print(a[10]) # This is an error
```

, the result is:

> []
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/imactuallyavegetable/temp.py", line 333, in
>   
>       print(a[10]) IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

First an empty array, second the exception.