# Divide each element by the next one in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I hope to do is be able to divide a value in a 1 dimensional numpy array by the following value. For example, I have an array that looks like this.

```
[ 0 20 23 25 27 28 29 30 30 22 20 19 19 19 19 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 ]
```

I want to do this:

```
0/20 #0th value divided by 1st value
20/23 #1st value divided by 2nd value
23/25 #2nd value divided by 3rd value
25/27 #3rd value divided by 4th value
etc...
```

I can easily do it through a loop, however I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this with numpy operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get two [`Slices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) - One from `start` to `last-1`, another from `start+1` to `last` and perform element-wise division -

```
a[:-1]/a[1:]
```

To get floating point divisions -

```
np.true_divide(a[:-1],a[1:])
```

Or put `from __future__ import division` and then use `a[:-1]/a[1:]`.

Being [`views`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array) into the input array, these slices are really efficiently accessed for element-wise division operation.

Sample run -

```
In [56]: a    # Input array
Out[56]: array([96, 81, 48, 53, 18, 92, 79, 43, 13, 69])

In [57]: from __future__ import division

In [58]: a[:-1]/a[1:]
Out[58]: 
array([ 1.18518519,  1.6875    ,  0.90566038,  2.94444444,  0.19565217,
        1.16455696,  1.8372093 ,  3.30769231,  0.1884058 ])

In [59]: a[0]/a[1]
Out[59]: 1.1851851851851851

In [60]: a[1]/a[2]
Out[60]: 1.6875

In [61]: a[2]/a[3]
Out[61]: 0.90566037735849059
```