# Can a slice of a numpy array be a view of another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I might have used the wrong terminology for this question, consequently there might have been a replicate of this question, but I was not able to find it.

In the following example, if it is possible, what would be the instruction in `In [16]` such that if b is modified, the slice of a `a[3:6]` is affected too ?

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: a = np.zeros((7))

In [14]: b = np.random.rand(3,)

In [15]: b
Out[15]: array([ 0.76954692,  0.74704679,  0.05969099])

In [16]: a[3:6] = b

In [17]: b[0] = 2.2

In [18]: a # a has not changed
Out[18]:
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.76954692,  0.74704679,
        0.05969099,  0.        ])
```

Comment: `In[16]` copies values from `b` to `a`.  It does not insert a link or reference to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

After the assignment `a[3:6] = b`, add the line `b = a[3:6]`. Then `b` becomes a *view* into the array `a`, and so a modification of `b` will modify `a` accordingly. (And the other way around).

A numeric NumPy array contains numbers (of the same `dtype`), not references or any other kinds of structure. The *entire* array may be a view of another array (in which case it uses its data instead of having its own), but a part of it cannot. Assignment to a slice always copies data.

Comment: Thanks ! This post provides additional information related to your answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array#4371049)

Comment: Can't we write `a[3:6] = b.view()` instead?

Comment: You can write that. It won't do what you hope it to do, but you can write that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write this:

```
a = np.zeros((7))
b = a[3:6]  # b is now a view to a

b[:] = np.random.rand(3)  # changes both b and a
                          # the [:] is so we don't create a new variable
```