# Can I create a numpy.ndarray as a view onto a native list?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy
pre_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
post_array = numpy.array(pre_list)
post_array[2] = 10
print(pre_list)
```

I notice that `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is printed, which means `pre_list` was not modified. I guess numpy copied each elements of `pre_list`, and it may cost time `cn`, where n is len(pre_list), c is a constant. Can I create an array as a view onto a native list, so that they can share elements?

I want to do so, because a list is given, I hope to implement an algorithm on it in a time complexity `logn`, but either use method functions of `ndarray` for convince.

Comment: The real question is why would you want to do so? Everything you can do with python `list`, you can do with `np.array`. So why don't you just work with a `np.array` from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View onto a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array)

Comment: The underlying structure of arrays and lists are too different.  A list contains pointers to objects elsewhere.  In this case 4 pointers to unique integers (in cPython integers up to 255 are unique).  The array reads the list, and constructs its own data buffer.  In this case its databuffer is 16 bytes (4x4).  `view` is a numpy concept, not a list one.