# why Numpy mutable variable such as array didn't update value on the same memory?

Tags: python, numpy, mutable

I am confused by the mutable variable in python. See the following example code:

```
In [144]: a=[1,2,3,4]

In [145]: b=a

In [146]: a.append(5)

In [147]: a
Out[147]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [148]: b
Out[148]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Since list is mutable, when using append function, it works on the same memory. This is understandable to me. But the following code confuses me.

```
In [149]: import numpy as np

In [150]: a=np.random.randn(3,2)

In [151]: b=a

In [152]: a=a-1

In [153]: a
Out[153]:
array([[-2.05342905, -1.21441195],
       [-1.29901352, -3.29416381],
       [-2.28775209, -1.65702149]])

In [154]: b
Out[154]:
array([[-1.05342905, -0.21441195],
       [-0.29901352, -2.29416381],
       [-1.28775209, -0.65702149]])
```

Since the Numpy array variable is **also** mutable, when **a=a-1**, why the change didn't be made on the same memory that **a** refers to?  On the other hand, **a** refers to a new memory with new values.
Why variable **a** didn't act similarly  in the first example about appending a new value 5 in the list, **a** still refers to the same memory?

Comment: a=a-1 is copy assignment. a-=1 would be mutable

Comment: a-=1 is not a copy assignment？ can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: No it is not. It is augmented assignment and python objects have a specific method for that (`__isub__`) which `numpy.ndarray` implements

Answer (score 2):

Because when you call `a=a-1` you are assigning a new value to variable a... then the whole memory allocation to this variable is changed since `a-1` isn't changing `a` in-place, and instead creates another object..

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = a
a = a + [4]
a 
>>> [1,2,3,4] 
b
>>> [1,2,3]
```

See? It has nothing to do with numpy specificly...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `a -= 1` is inplace but `a = a-1` copies memory of `a` to another place and then subtracts `1`. Therefore, the location where `a` originally pointed, changes.

You can check this using `is`. The `is` keyword says if two variables refer to the same object in memory or not, it is different from `==`.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randn(3,2)
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> a, b
(array([[-0.14563848,  2.11951025],
       [ 0.50913228, -0.61049821],
       [ 2.29055958, -0.83795141]]), array([[-0.14563848,  2.11951025],
       [ 0.50913228, -0.61049821],
       [ 2.29055958, -0.83795141]]))
>>> a -= 1
>>> a
array([[-1.14563848,  1.11951025],
       [-0.49086772, -1.61049821],
       [ 1.29055958, -1.83795141]])
>>> b
array([[-1.14563848,  1.11951025],
       [-0.49086772, -1.61049821],
       [ 1.29055958, -1.83795141]])
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = a - 1
>>> a
array([[-2.14563848,  0.11951025],
       [-1.49086772, -2.61049821],
       [ 0.29055958, -2.83795141]])
>>> b
array([[-1.14563848,  1.11951025],
       [-0.49086772, -1.61049821],
       [ 1.29055958, -1.83795141]])
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: So the operation `-=` is similar to the `append`, works as inplace, but why? Do you have more examples related to inplace operation?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370745/view-onto-a-numpy-array